# Serialized string to array in PHP

Tags: php

I receive a string from jQuery UI Sortable plugin, it gives me a string like this one

```
items[]=1&items[]=2&items[]=3
```

How can I trun it into a real array?

I was thinking replacing `&` with `;` and asserting it. Any better suggestions?

Comment: You should receive this as $_POST or $_GET, how are you even sending the output of sortable to your php in the first place?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for [`parse_str()`.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

> Parses str as if it were the query string passed via a URL and sets variables in the current scope.

For example:

```
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz
```

You can also specify an array to store results in if you do not want to pollute your scope:

```
parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) :)

Comment: @Phoenix I think it's pretty sure to link to the php doc :)

Answer (score -1):

```
// I am assuming you are getting this value from post or get method;

$string = implode(";", $_REQUEST['items']);
echo $string;
```